# Monorepo - lock app to stay on specific package version

Tags: version-control, monorepo, pnpm

I have a monorepo, that contains packages, and apps that are using those packages.
I am using pnpm workspaces on all apps with `workspace:*`

Now I've updated on of the packages with breaking changes, and one app is not ready to for it, is there any way to tell it to use previous version, other than not aliasing `workspace`, so instead `workspace:*` I would have to use `^1.2.3` ?

I am just wondering if there is a rule or common practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to lock the application to older/specific version of package.
You can use [changesets](https://pnpm.io/using-changesets) for that, you have to publish the version and use changesets to lock application to use that version.

[image: ][1]][1]]

see [docs](https://pnpm.io/using-changesets) for more information

sample [repo](https://github.com/AdnanShah/mono-repo-with-changesets)

You can also use [Meta](https://github.com/mateodelnorte/meta) to do the same, the idea is to use package commit hash to lock a package to use specific commit hash something like this (`"ui-package": "github:UserName/common#26fcbeecbce7ab2661a044bc22635feec8e3bd1d"`).

sample [repo](https://github.com/AdnanShah/mono-repo-with-changesets/tree/dev)