# Solution for versioning packages inside a monorepo

Tags: vue.js, npm, architecture, monorepo

My team and I are working on restructuring our frontend codebase (nuxt + vue.js) in order to speed up development of the upcoming projects. We have a `Product1` that we customise per customer (hence creating `Product1_A`, `Product1_B` etc). What we're thinking of doing is to create a monorepo that will contain our common packages, common product1 package and the specific implementations for the customers. The challange we're facing is that `Product1_A` could potentially depend on a different version of a `CommonPackage1` or `CommonProduct1Package` than `Product1_B`. We might also introduce a `Product2` into the repository, which implementations might also depend on different version of the common packages.

An obvious way of solving this is to have all the packages in separate repositories and handle versioning there, but the common packages will change a lot (at least initially), so having them in one codebase would be beneficial. Is there any tool supporting this kind of use case? What would be the best practice here?

We're considering tools like `Lerna`, `NX`, `Turborepo`, `pnpm`, also `npm workspaces`

Comment: The obvious problem with a monorepo is that it's a monorepo. Given that package versions are identified by git tags, you can't use different versions simultaneously this way, so proceed from that. Holding common packages together in a monorepo would prevent separate packages from being used directly as a dep without publishing to npm repo (through git submodule, or npm git source, or npm link). It's more likely that a monorepo can be used for products, while common packages are in separate repos.

Comment: this should help you (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76929125/9934523)